# Link to Meta and Main website

Tags: support, meta, top-bar

I think that although there are links in the footer, links to Meta site and Main site should be given in the menu bar as well, preferably with an icon.

In their absence, I usually find myself changing the URL directly.

Comment: There are already questions which should be posted on the main site posted on meta and visa versa, doing that would only exacerbate the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why? How does this improve the site?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think this will improve navigation.

Comment: That's a statement, not an elaboration. Why do you think it improves navigation?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth a single click for navigation is anyways easiest for changing thpough pages.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: Forgot bout that. Oops!

Comment: That's a very strange red you have there. Is your paint installation colour blind or something?